# How to compare columns of type character between two dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, find, compare, character

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2:

```
    df1 = data.frame("text" = c("fht49_169_fcxrtvf", "fht49_169_fcxrtvf","fht15_18_trddrefx", "fht15_18_trddrefx", "fht15_18_trddrefx", "fht28_18_ptybrwdf", "fht1_1_tyhfvcs", "fht33_151_tyhfvcs", "fht20_14_gfhyqrsx"), 
                  "values_x" = c(3,55,11,3,5,4,8,33,1))
    df2 = data.frame("text" = c("fht49_169_fcxrtvf", "fht15_18_trddrefx", "fht28_18_ptybrwdf", "fht33_151_tyhfvcs"), 
                 "values_x" = c(3,11,3,5))
```

df1

| text | values_x |
| --- | --- |
| fht49_169_fcxrtvf | 3 |
| fht49_169_fcxrtvf | 55 |
| fht15_20_trddrefx | 11 |
| fht15_20_trddrefx | 3 |
| fht15_18_trddrefx | 5 |
| fht28_18_ptybrwdf | 4 |
| fht1_1_tyhfvcs | 8 |
| fht33_151_tyhfvcs | 33 |
| fht20_14_gfhyqrsx | 1 |

df2

| text | values_x |
| --- | --- |
| fht49_169_fcxrtvf | 3 |
| fht15_18_trddrefx | 11 |
| fht28_18_ptybrwdf | 3 |
| fht33_151_tyhfvcs | 5 |

I need to compare df1$text and df2$text and find the unique strings that are present in df1 but not in df2. The result should be printed and saved in a vector or any other type of object.
The result from the comparison above should return:

`fht15_20_trddrefx, fht1_1_tyhfvcs, fht20_14_gfhyqrsx`

Comment: `setdiff(df1$text, df2$text)` should work

Comment: try this ```df1$text[!df1$text %in% df2$text]```

Comment: I can't make out where `fht15_20_trddrefx` comes into play, as related to desired output, as both the above comments work(ish).

Comment: @peter861222 adding unique() to your solution, it works! Thanks

Comment: `dplyr`s `anti_join` could also be an option: `anti_join(df1, df2, by = "text")`.